# Finicky cats and what to do

Tags: cats, diet, feeding, domestication

My three cats are the most finicky cats I’ve ever had and, since one is allergic to chicken, it makes things even worse. They eat gravy and sauce and then they walk. I throw away food every day and it’s costing me a fortune. I’ve tried everything on the market and they hate it all. Should I just let them go hungry for a while? I don’t know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 3):

What we do is five small meals a day, feeding all three of our cats from the same 80-100 gram foil package. That way less goes to waste if the current offering displeases one or two of them.

The total amount in a foil package is still small enough that even one cat can pretty much finish it if off if the two others refuse, and even though they are a little more expensive than large cans, the foil packages tend to be accepted more.

Apparently it tastes better due to the different heating process, but I can't personally comment on that.

---

What does definitely work better with foil packages is placing them in hot water for a minute or two, or place them on top of a heating outlet, to get the food roughly to body temperature before serving.

Cats in nature eat fresh prey which is still warm, and a little more temperature also intensifies the smell.

---

We also tend to have a wide selection available and try to not give the same thing twice a day to keep it interesting.

---

If you can manage, a small play session just before feeding is perfect to tie into their natural rhythm of hunt-kill-eat-groom-sleep and helps to stimulate their appetite.

Comment: Which foil food? One of my cats is allergic to chicken. I was thinking of using a small blender to make it more inviting. Next is the starve menu. They also hate baby food.

Comment: @CherylGuerbaoui We have multiple brands, some higher quality like 'Almo Nature' but also some low-end, fast-food style like 'Felix'. What we found though is that even with the exact same brand and sort, the larger aluminum cans get rejected a lot more than the smaller soft-packs. Plus, if they do not finish a soft pack, that means whatever is left of 85 grams goes to waste, while with the large cans what is left of 200 grams or even 400 grams for the extra large cans goes to waste.